# Adjust height of Storyboard-created UITableview to height of its contents

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I've dragged a table view into my storyboard scene, but its height is static and won't adjust based on how many cells it contains unless I manually adjust it in storyboard. How can I get this table to adjust its own height based on the total height of its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to do some version of this:

1. Figure out how many cells will be displayed
2. Figure out the height for each cell
3. Do the math and set the height of the `UITableView`

Before you get mad (since I know that's pretty obvious), let me follow up with this:

1. If you know for sure how many cells will be displayed all the time (and it's a static value), you can just manually adjust the height in Interface Builder.
2. If you *don't* know for sure (which I'm guessing is the case, based on your question), you'll have to do #'s 1 thru 3 above at runtime. Then, because `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIView`, you can simply adjust its `frame` property.

For example:

1. I've got 7 cells.
2. Cells 1, 3 and 5 (indices 0, 2 and 4) are 20 pixels tall.
3. Cells 2, 4, 6 and 7 (indices 1, 3, 5 and 6) are 30 pixels tall.
4. I need a total display height of 180 pixels (you might actually need to play with this because of separators, etc..)
5. So, I can just call:

---

```
CGFloat newHeight = ... // Whatever you calculate
CGRect currentFrame = [[self MyTableView] frame];  
[[self MyTableView] setFrame:CGRectMake(
                 currentFrame.origin.x,
                 currentFrame.origin.y,
                 currentFrame.size.width,
                 newHeight)
 ];
```

If you want to get really fancy, you can animate the change by wrapping it in a `[UIView animationWithDuration:]` block.

Hope this helps!

---

***Update/Edit***

Here's a kludgy way to do it... it works, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it. I ***do not*** claim this to be the best/fastest/most efficient way. This is more to show a principle. ;-)

```
- (CGFloat)totalHeightNeededForTableView:(UITableView *)tv {
    CGFloat retVal = 0;

    int sectionCount = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tv];
    int rowCount = 0;
    NSIndexPath *path = nil;
    for (int i = 0; i < sectionCount; i = i + 1) {
        rowCount = [self tableView:tv numberOfRowsInSection:i];
        for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j = j + 1) {
            path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i];
            retVal = retVal + [self tableView:tv heightForRowAtIndexPath:path];
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: What do you think is the best way of adding up all the heights of the cells to get a newHeight?

Comment: Well, you kind of *have* to provide the `UITableView` a way to do that with `numberOfSections...`, `numberOfRowsInSection...`, `heightForRow...`. So, you could call those and work it out for yourself. Or, if you've got a basic implementation (like, 1 array that **is** the table's data), you could just iterate the array and figure out the row height for each cell that ***would*** be made from that data.